# Mongo console doesn't behave properly in ansi-term

Tags: interactive, ansi-term

In ansi-term when using mongo console (or 'repl') control codes do not seem to behave properly.

When I move cursor it doesn't get redrawn at a expected location. Instead all entered text get appended to the input. The same goes for backspace. My input does get interpreted, however, it is not displayed correctly.

[image: example]

Here's result of typing 'testtest', then pressing backspace.
$TERMINFO value is set to 'eterm-color'

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Off-topic: Is that nyan cat actually part of your Emacs setup, or did you just use it to censor sensitive info?

Comment: Do you have an `eterm-color` terminfo entry installed? e.g. under `/usr/share/terminfo/e/` or `~/.terminfo/e/` ?

Comment: @ScottWeldon I believe it is part of emacs. I use spacemacs, and there is a `color` layer with that nyan cat thing.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly solve the issue, but I've noticed that if you run tmux inside ansi-term (or byobu in my case, which is running tmux under the covers) it fixes the issue with the mongo shell.  Not sure why that is.

Just resetting the value of TERM to something else (even "screen", which is what tmux sets it to) doesn't solve the problem, but actually running mongo from inside tmux works properly.

Comment: You can think of screen/tmux being much more capable terminal emulators than ansi-term to the applications running inside them while both still run acceptably well inside Emacs.